# AzureAD B2C Auth in Xamarin Forms Mobile Application with Microsoft Authenticator App

Tags: c#, .net-core, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory

**Development**: Visual Studio 2019, Xamarin Forms Mobile Application targeting .Net 5, written in C#.

**Architecture**: Public facing mobile application, Azure hosted API, Azure hosted sql server instance.

I've been learning mobile application development in my spare time so that I can begin doing mobile work for my employer. I would appreciate any guidance or design help on this based on the requirements.

**Requirements**: Employee logs into the mobile application via AzureAD B2CAuthentication and has to do multi factor authentication via the Microsoft Authenticator app. I believe I have found all I need to make this part work: [azure-ad-b2c](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c) using the MSAL library and the example project on GIT at [XamarinFormsMFASample](https://github.com/rzdebskiy/XamarinFormsMFASample). Once authenticated, the user would then receive a token which they could then use to make API calls, the API should be able to authenticate the user via the token received in the Authentication piece. The API would then sit between the mobile application and the database, this way no connection strings or sensitive data is stored within the mobile application code.

1. Am I on the right track here? I thought I read that in Azure configuration, I could add my API as a hosted service and then have the authentication piece send back a token for the API?? Or will I be able to leverage some library to read the authentication token received in step 1 in my API to ensure the user is authenticated and part of our domain?
2. Am I on the right track for the authentication piece? Has anyone used this kind of authentication before? The user would input their sAMAccount name and password and be authenticated via that against AzureAD and then complete MFA via the Microsoft Authenticator Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how an authentication request would flow, from a mobile client that needs to access a REST API - both of which are members of the same AD B2C Tenant.

**1. Invoke the Sign-In Policy**

When using MSAL - this will automatically display a login page (in a WebView) that will let the user authenticate with the allowed providers for that policy.

**2. AD B2C Returns a Token (and any other user info)**

Using OAuth 2.0 - AD B2C will return an access token that the app will eventually send on to the REST API it wants access to. AD B2C also will send back any information about the user (such as display name) that the policy allows.

**3.Mobile Client Sends Access Token To REST API**

The mobile client will send the newly acquired access token to the REST API as a bearer token in the request to get whatever information its after.

**4.REST API Check Token Against AD B2C**

Now it's the REST API's turn to use the AD B2C to check the access token - to make sure it's a valid token.

**5.REST API Sends a Response**

Finally - the REST API either sends the information requested - if the authorization was good - or it sends a 401 response. Generally speaking - it should send the information back, because the user was already authenticated. Unless the user was trying to access a resource they weren't authorized to use and authorization is a whole other blog post.

To make it more clear, I simply drew a diagram：
[image]

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you for the confirmation on this. I thought this was the correct flow, but I wanted to make sure I was reading it correctly before diving into writing code. Could you verify that during the authentication token request from AD B2C from the mobile device that it can indeed do the MFA flow using Microsoft Authenticator app?

Comment: @adrianzhu also, do you have any good documentation of Step 4. Verifying the access token in the web api?

Comment: You can refer to this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-sign-in-flow